# Httpserver java send html with css/js/library

Tags: java, html, httpserver

when I try to load the page in the server's contentpath "\manager" it should send the response of page manager.html complete with css and the various libraries used. The server send the page, the only problem does not execute the javascript present inside (with the corresponding images and css).

```
@Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        String root = "html/manager";

        URI uri = he.getRequestURI();

        File file = new File(root + uri.getPath()+ ".html").getCanonicalFile();
        OutputStream os = null;
        String response = "";

        System.out.println(root + uri.getPath());

        if (!file.isFile()) {
          // Object does not exist or is not a file: reject with 404 error.
          response = "404 (Not Found)\n";
          he.sendResponseHeaders(404, response.length());
          os = he.getResponseBody();
          os.write(response.getBytes());

        } else {
          // Object exists and is a file: accept with response code 200.
          he.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
          os = he.getResponseBody();
          FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
          final byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
          int count = 0;
          while ((count = fs.read(buffer)) >= 0) os.write(buffer,0,count);  
          fs.close();

        }
        os.close();
    }
```

Console output:

> html/manager/manager

[HTML server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDC2e.png)

[Opening local .html file with browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2eDw.png)

Path:

> /.../Applicazione/Illumify/html/manager/manager.html

[doc folder used inside the manager.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrwYw.png)